# array item not adding but replaces current item?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
     Attributes
    .saveAttribute($scope.attribute, function() {
      toastr.success('Attribute added successfully', 'Success');
      $scope.modalInstance.dismiss();


      var arr=[];
      arr.push($scope.attribute.parentAttribute.id)
      console.log(arr);

  setTimeout(function () {

             for( var i=$scope.arr.length-1;i>=0;i--)
             {
              angular.element(document.getElementById(arr[i])).click();
             }
          },1000);
```

when i push id of a button to array the array item is not adding, it replaces the current id... how to fix it.
i have tried taking that array declaration outside, but doesnt worked.
pls help........

Comment: `var arr != $scope.arr`

Comment: still same result.... doesnt evn matter if $scope or $rootscope or var all gave replacing array....

Comment: please post your controller code completely

Comment: Can you post your code in jsfiddle.net or codepen.io and share the link?

Answer (score 0):

Your array should be a `$scope` variable.

```
 $scope.arr=[];
 $scope.arr.push($scope.attribute.parentAttribute.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the `var array` above the  `$scope.attribute`.

```
 var arr=[];

 Attributes
.saveAttribute($scope.attribute, function() {
  toastr.success('Attribute added successfully', 'Success');
  $scope.modalInstance.dismiss();

  arr.push($scope.attribute.parentAttribute.id)

  setTimeout(function () {

         for( var i=$scope.arr.length-1;i>=0;i--)
         {
          angular.element(document.getElementById(arr[i])).click();
         }
      },1000);
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: still same result... simply replacing...
i tried $scope.arr and $rootscope.arr nothing worked

Comment: Hi could you try to `console.log(arr)` after the `.saveAttribute` function?

Comment: getting an empty array

Comment: Could you post your whole controller codes. I would like to check it.

Comment: Sorry I am busy. I created a chatroom. We can discuss it here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103943/array